# Is it possible to create 50 dropdowns with less code and best practice?

Tags: flutter, dart

I had to create 50 drop down. I used 50 variables. and 50 drop down. Is it possible to do it less code with best practice?

50 drop down button I created

```
       DropdownButton<String>(
          underline: SizedBox(),
          value: selectSun,
          iconEnabledColor: Palette.darkSilver,
          onChanged: selectSun == 'Close'?null:
          ((value) {
            setState(() {
              selectSun = value;
            });
          }),
          items: status.map((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: CustomText(
                text: value,
                textColor: Palette.redButton,
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
```

and also 50 variables

```
 String selectSunFromHour = '09';
```

and also I set these data to firebase. I set one by one

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
          Column(
            children: languages.map<DropdownButton<String>>((String value) {
              return DropdownButton<String>(
                // Dropdown button init here, value is from languages
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
```

Comment: Accually i still not understand what are you trying to implement. I just show you how to create a list DropdownButton with a list Object. setState still work for every DropdownButton i think